Formal power series over the sphere spectrum?
In Section 11 of their paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03261, Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze discuss the polynomial algebra over the sphere spectrum. I'm wondering whether its possible to define a notion of formal power series over the sphere spectrum and, if so, where this is discussed?

The formal power series ring $\mathbb S[![t]!]$ is just the $t$-completion of the polynomial ring $\mathbb S[t]$: the $t$-completion functor $D(\mathbb S[t])\to D(\mathbb S[t])$ carries a canonical lax symmetric monoidal, thus it sends an $E_\infty$-algebra to an $E_\infty$-algebra.

@Z.M What's a reference for this kind of completion?

Lurie's Spectral Algebraic Geometry, and more precisely, section 7.3.5. For this particular formal power series, you even have $\mathbb S[![t]!]=\lim_n\mathbb S[t]/t^n$ where each $\mathbb S[t]/t^n$ is a monoidal ring.

@Z.M Thank you I appreciate your reply.
